# ¿Problema de rendimiento en java?

Tags: java

un saludo para todos. Me gustaria validar si a alguien mas le ha sucedido un aparente problema asociado a los botones de java. Tengo una serie de bonotes en una GUI sencilla y no toma el ActionPerformed al primer click(Tengo que oprimir una segunda vez para que se ejecute el codigo). Luego de este evento los botones funciona con normalidad(Un solo click).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo: El primer botono NUEVO, debo oprimirlo dos veces, luego de estos los demas bonotes trabajan normal.

Agradezco su colaboración

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ya que no es la funcionalidad esperada, seria interesante ver si hay algun problema en el codigo tambien

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SO. Primero, prueba a ponernos tu código, concretamente el que usas en los eventos del clic en los botones. Nos ayudará también saber qué API de interfaz gráfica usas.